# How to protect or hide a web application on GlassFish?

Tags: glassfish, password-protected

I have to deploy a ready web application on a public GlassFish instance. The itself has user management and users must be registered to login as we all know it. However I have to protected or hide the whole webapplication in such a way, that only specific users can access the web application.

I am looking for a simple possibility to have a kind of frontpage with an extra password without modifying the application itself.